# How to get current tab position correctly for bottombar in android?

Tags: android, uinavigationbar

I used setDefaultTabPosition(and/or selectTabAtPosition) to **set tab position at 2**, I got **tab 2**'s **title/icon**(string/image) highlighted from the screen, this is expected.

But the **content**(a fragment) is still show with **tab 0's**.

I found that's because the getCurrentTabPosition() not return the correct tab position. See below code. Expect to see 2 but got 0.

I did an experiment put getCurrentTabPosition() inside the listener, it seems working correctly. (but always 0 before any click on the tab)

Is that a bug, or I miss something?

The Log.e result of below code: E/currTabPosition: 0

```
    int temp=2;

    // I tried both, any one of them
    bottomBar.setDefaultTabPosition(currBb); 
    bottomBar.selectTabAtPosition(temp);

    temp = bottomBar.getCurrentTabPosition();

    Log.e("currTabPosition", ""+temp);
```

Below linke is the bottombar project:

https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Comment: One more bug? If I set default tab at position 2, then it always active on screen even I click 0 and/or 1, until 2 clicked.

Answer (score 1):

- Default Position

```
    bottomBar.setDefaultTabPosition(0);
```

- Setting up listeners

```
    bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
            if (tabId == R.id.tab_favorites) {

            }
        }
    });
```